# partial_sum, destination range same as input. guaranteed to work?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer

Basically I want to replace the values in the `vector` by the corresponding `partial_sum`. And I can not find in the reference whether it is guaranteed to work in case the destination range is the same as input.

And what about `inclusive_scan`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's guaranteed to work. The standard mentioned this, [$26.8.6/5 Partial sum [partial.sum]](http://eel.is/c++draft/partial.sum#5)

> 5 *Remarks:* `result` may be equal to `first`.

And it's same for `inclusive_scan`. [$26.8.8/6 Inclusive scan
[inclusive.scan]](http://eel.is/c++draft/inclusive.scan#6)

> 6 *Remarks:* `result` may be equal to `first`.